# FIPS-Compliant SHA2

Tags: sha-256, sha-2, sha-512, fips-140

I want to use SHA-512 for hashing in a system that must be FIPS-compliant. When I look at [the FIPS 140 list of approved providers](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/140val-all.htm), I don't see SHA from any provider as being an approved algorithm, I only see it as an "other" algorithm. [In FIPS 180, SHA-512 is listed as being approved](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips180-4/fips-180-4.pdf), although I don't see any specific references for approved providers.

Is there another list of approved providers of SHA-512 (or SHA-256, or whatever) that I have not found? Or is there no list of approved providers because they are all acceptable for use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it's there on the list, just with a different name -- the approved algorithm you want is listed as "SHS" (Secure Hashing Standard).

Now, the term "SHS" doesn't distinguish between the various flavors of SHA-2 (and SHA-1, which is still approved for some uses); however if you look at [this database](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/validated-modules/search), you can look up a specific module and see what it supports. Go to [advanced] and then type in SHS in the [algorithm] field (but beware that many tokens support SHA-2, so the list will be rather extensive). They [used to put it everything into a text file](https://web.archive.org/web/20180918070617/https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/cryptographic-algorithm-validation-program/validation/validation-list/shs); it appears they moved away from that at some point.

(Oh, and in case you're wondering, the designation "BYTE-only" means that an implementation can only hash sequences of bytes, while "BIT" means that they can hash arbitrary bit strings; for example, a sequence of 73 bits).  Of course, for virtually all purposes, "BYTE-only" is sufficient.